# Missing data points in line chart

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Plotly has missing data points on the graph that are present in the x and y lists which are being used to draw the graph. I am not sure why.

The x_axist_list is a list of year-week formats. So 2019-43 for instance would be week 43 of 2019.

```
x_axis_list = ['2019-00', '2019-01', '2019-02',.....'2019-54']
y_axis_list = [0,0,0,....1,2,0,0]
```

When I draw this out using Plotly:

```
my_fig = px.line(x=x_axis_list, y=y_axis_list,\
labels=dict(time_from_db="Time", \
num_of_accidents_from_db="Num of Accidents"), \
title="Number of Accidents Per Week")

dcc.Graph(id='my_fig', figure=my_fig)
```

I get weird line charts that looks something like the below figure.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gaps in your graph consistently fall on the end of a year so you might have an issue with how the last week(s) is represented in your data. Your example data doesn't show a transition from one year to the next, so I can't tell for sure.

Whatever the cause, you should be able to connect the gaps by making the following call after creating your figure:

```
my_fig.update_traces(connectgaps=True)
```